# 1045, "Access denied" using two python files, one work, another "Access denied"?

Tags: python, mysql

Using the same mdb.connect line in both files. Work with debian 7 and my problem is now to give to you more details cause I use to much code in my question, but I don't nothing more to tell.
File 1 works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'passw', 'pizzadb2', charset='utf8')

with con:

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pizzeria_table3")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE pizzeria_table3(pizzeria_Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
            laden_name VARCHAR(50), vorwahl VARCHAR(15), telenr1 VARCHAR(20), \
            telenr2 VARCHAR(20), fax VARCHAR(20), strasse VARCHAR(40), hausnr VARCHAR(20), \
            plz VARCHAR(20), ort VARCHAR(40), oeffz1 VARCHAR(40), oeffz2 VARCHAR(40), \
            oeffz3 VARCHAR(40), oeffz4 VARCHAR(40), bestellwert1 VARCHAR(60), \
            bestellwert2 VARCHAR(60),bestellwert3 VARCHAR(60),rumpf_daten VARCHAR(60), \
            html_name VARCHAR(40), kartenname VARCHAR(30), linkname1 VARCHAR(40),\
            linkname2 VARCHAR(40), linkname3 VARCHAR(40), ordner VARCHAR(100), \
            spaltenanzahl INTEGER, logo_ordner VARCHAR(60), logo_name VARCHAR(60), \
            forum_link VARCHAR(100), link2 VARCHAR(40), link3 VARCHAR(40), banner VARCHAR(100), \
            UNIQUE(vorwahl, telenr1)) \
            default character set 'UTF8' COLLATE utf8_general_ci")
```

File 2 'datenimport4.py' goes wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'passw', 'pizzadb2', charset='utf8')


with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE 'Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'\
            INTO TABLE pizzeria_table3 \
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
            ENCLOSED BY '\"' \
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'  \
            IGNORE 1 LINES \
            (laden_name, vorwahl, telenr1, strasse, hausnr, \
            ort, linkname1, linkname2, linkname3, forum_link, \
            link2, link3, banner) \
            ")
```

Here the error:

```
gutschy@kiste:~/pizza/pizza_daten$ python datenimport4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "datenimport4.py", line 21, in <module>")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in
defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I've checked MySQL grants too.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `pizzadb2`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'

The forum asked me more code, but don't no how I could explain my problem more spezifik

Comment: Just in case: is `Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv` accessible to the user which runs the MySQL _server?_

Comment: Yes, it's all readable, lies in the same folder and from the same user. <-- if my english bad, I'm from Germany, sorry. Have I to change something?

Comment: are you trying to access the database from both files at the same time?

Comment: No, there are minutes between. My main problem is, all works fine a few month before. But I have built my pc new. but still using the same debian.

Comment: You can make the file world-readable (`chmod a+r Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv`) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the user you are using has not enough permissions. The CSV file is being read from the data directory of the MySQL server and you are executing the script with user 'gutschy', but the MySQL server is (probably) running using the system user 'mysql'.

However, you probably want to load the data a bit differently. You want to use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` (note the 'LOCAL' keyboard). This means that the file will be uploaded to the MySQL server and then imported.

Here are the relevant changes to your code:

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'passw', 'pizzadb2', charset='utf8'
                  local_infile=1)

..
with con:
    ..
    cur.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'\
    ..
```

For this to work, however, you need to change the MySQL server configuration. On Debian I like to do it adding an extra option file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/server.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
```

Restart the MySQL server, and try your script using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Permissions should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's done. :) I'm not shure, but is there the possibility to add MySQLdb to the user group?

Comment: You can add the user with which you execute your script to the mysql system group, but you _should not_ do that. You script should connect to MySQL server and properly use the MySQL privilege system and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

check access privileges on both Adressliste_forum1_v5.csv AND it's directory. the user running the MySQL server (NOT the user granted privs in the MySQL configuration, the UNIX user that mysql process is running under - you can check this with `ps aux | grep mysql`)

the file must at least have read privileges for the user, and its parent directory must have execute privileges.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean:gutschy   6817  0.0  0.0  40280  3000 pts/0    S+   01:25   0:00 mysql -u root -p
gutschy   6967  0.0  0.0   9900   912 pts/1    S+   02:03   0:00 grep mysql .this is mine normal user

Comment: And could call MySQL root from him.